# Custom message box class has terminal "pop up" when the form does

Tags: c#, winforms

Alright, this is a little strange, but essentially I needed a message box class with buttons that did not come as options within the message box class in c#. Therefore, I read up on how to create my own class (here is the link if your interested: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1086b27f-683c-457a-b00e-b80b48d69ef5/custom-buttons-in-messagebox?forum=csharpgeneral), and used an example provided inside of that. Here is the relevant code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public static bool MessageSucceded { get; set; }
  public static string MessageContent{ private get; set; }

  private void buttonMyMessageBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {   
   using (MyMessageForm myForm = new MyMessageForm())
  {
    myForm.ShowDialog();
    if (MessageSucceded = myForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
     if (MessageContent== "Yes do it")
     {
       //HERE DO WHAT YOU WANT IF THE USER CLICKS ON BUTTON YES DO IT
     }
     else if (MessageContent== "No, don`t do it")
    {
      //HERE DO WHAT YOU WANT IF THE USER CLICKS ON BUTTON NO, DON`T DO IT
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

public partial class MyMessageForm : Form
{
 private void MyMessageForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
   this.ShowIcon = false;
   this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
   this.MinimizeBox = false;
   this.MaximizeBox = false;
   this.buttonYes.Text = "Yes do it";
   this.buttonNo.Text = "No, don`t do it";
   this.labelMyForm.Text = "Are you sure you want to… ?";
 }

 private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Form1.MessageSucceded = true;
   Form1.MessageContent= buttonYes.Text;
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
   this.Close();
 }

 private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Form1.MessageSucceded = true;
   Form1.MessageContent= buttonNo.Text;
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
   this.Close();
 }
}
```

This works exactly as I intended it to, except for one small detail. Just before the message box pops up, for a split second, a terminal version of the message box form opens up, before it closes on its own and the windows form version opens and functions as expected. I can't understand why this is happening, and it isn't causing any performance issues that I can notice, but aesthetically it looks very bad. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to stop it? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express for what its worth. Thanks for any help you have and taking the time to read this.

Edit: heres my code for main:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking `ShowDialog()` twice:

```
myForm.ShowDialog();
if (MessageSucceded = myForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
```

Form has been closed so it'll close immediatly, right way to do it is to save its first result and check that in your `if` condition:

```
var result = myForm.ShowDialog();
if (MessageSucceded = (result == DialogResult.OK)) {
```

Or directly:

```
MessageSucceded = myForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK;
if (MessageSucceded) {
```

Moreover if you returns different results according to clicked button then you do not need to compare `MessageContent` (it's also a bad idea to have a reference to caller just to return a result):

```
private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
    this.Close();
}

 private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
    this.Close();
 }
```

Note that now you can simply remove such code and add proper `DialogResult` property to each button (because assign `Form.DialogResult` and call `Form.Close()` is default behavior if `Button.DialogResult` property is assigned). Done that you can simply use it like this:

```
switch (myForm.ShowDialog())
{
    case DialogResult.Yes:
        break;
    case DialogResult.No:
    case DialogResult.Cancel: // Unless ControlBox is also Hidden
        break;
}
```

As last note: if you're targeting Vista+ you may also check Task Dialog instead of writing a custom form (you may keep it as fallback for XP's users).

Comment: I tryed doing it directly like you suggested, but now the terminal is the only thing to show up for the split second. The form never does

Comment: @Sporkley terminal? Be sure your program's **Output Type** is **Windows Application** and not **Console Application**.

Comment: yeah, I checked that before I posted this, that was my first guess

Comment: Really, console must not appear unless you're targeting .NET 1.0 or a Console Application...can you post a full working example that repro that problem?

Comment: if i run the exact code I have in my question it does this

Comment: and if you take out the myForm.ShowDialog(); line, the form doesn't show up at all, just the terminal for a split second

Comment: @Sporkley I see but a terminal should not come out. Code is not complete (try to create a fresh new winforms project, add a button and that code). BTW you may want to move initialization from Load event to constructor.

Comment: I did that and still got the same issue in a fresh project running exactly what is seen here much to my puzzlement :/

Comment: I put it in my question

Comment: @Sporkley what do you mean with "terminal version of MessageBox"? At first I thought you're talking about a console window but probably it's not. Did you move your initialization code from `MyMessageForm_Load` to `MyMessageForm` (constructor) or (much better) do it directly inside designer?

Comment: no, i hadn't moved it. that seems to have solved the problem, thanks for you time, its much appreciated :)